# Retrieve the value of each field in Angular FormGroup

Tags: angular

I just want to retrieve the value of each field (number: "9190000471", internationalNumber: "+91 91900 00471", nationalNumber: "091900 00471", e164Number: "+919190000471") in a ForGroup, any idea on how to do that. I'm trying to use a js library for International Telephone Input for Angular (NgxIntlTelInput) and it has an existing example in stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-ng-10?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). I attached the screenshoot of the specific element in  formgroup where the value should come from.[image: FormGroup value element]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change your html file where you have added ngx-intl-tel-input like as follows -

```
 <ngx-intl-tel-input (change)="getValues()" [cssClass]="'custom'" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries"
            [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true" [enablePlaceholder]="true" [searchCountryFlag]="true"
            [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]" [selectFirstCountry]="false"
            [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.India" [maxLength]="15" [tooltipField]="TooltipLabel.Name"
            [phoneValidation]="true" [separateDialCode]="separateDialCode"
            [numberFormat]="PhoneNumberFormat.National" name="phone" formControlName="phone">
 </ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

I have added change function here and to retrieve its value in .ts file i have added one function as below : -

```
getValues() {
   console.log(this.phoneForm.controls["phone"].value.countryCode);
   console.log(this.phoneForm.controls["phone"].value.dialCode);
   console.log(this.phoneForm.controls["phone"].value.e164Number);
   console.log(this.phoneForm.controls["phone"].value.internationalNumber);
   console.log(this.phoneForm.controls["phone"].value.nationalNumber);
   console.log(this.phoneForm.controls["phone"].value.number);
 }
```

This will retrieve all your values and you can check it in your browser console window. You can refer here - [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-ng-10-bdsrko?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)